# Render HTML DOM Node in React Component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am using Wordpress as my CMS and creating some of the pages in React and rendering it. I have a use case where i need to render HTML DOM Node inside of my React Component. I am getting the DOM Node with the help of querySelector() which returns me the DOM node. In React i am trying to render it using React.createElement. But it renders as [object HTMLDivElement] on my page.

```
 render() {
      const { reactPages } = this.props;
      const innerPages = React.createElement('div', {id: "myDiv"}, `${reactPages.children[0]}`);
      
      return (
        <div className="react-cmp-container">
          <h3>React Container</h3>
          { innerPages }
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
```

The other thing i tried was using the dangerouslySetInnerHTML:

```
 rawMarkUp = () => {
      const { reactPages } = this.props;

      return {__html: reactPages}
    }

    render() {

      const innerPages = React.createElement('div', {id: "myDiv"}, )
      
      return (
        <div className="react-cmp-particle-container">
          <h3>React Particle Container</h3>
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.rawMarkUp()}></div>
        </div>
      )
    }
```

This is the type of DOM Node that i am getting and passing it as props to my Component.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the `React.render()` function to make sure you are rendering the DOM element.

Comment: @shn In my ReactDOM.render i am rendering my component where i am trying to print the DOM Node. ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, element);

Comment: @shn Even if i try to render the Node in React.render is gives an error as : Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLDivElement])

Comment: Please reproduce in codesandbox

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not recommended to to. It might cause many kinds of trouble later. Anyway, ...

`querySelector()` returns a `DOM-element` (or collection of such).

#### 1. `React.createElement`

`React.createElement` does **not work**, because it expects another `React.Element`, or a `string`, not a `DOM-element`.

#### 2. `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

`dangerouslySetInnerHTML` does **not work**, because it expects a HTML *string*, not a `DOM-element`.

You could use `domElement.innerHTML` and put the HTML string into `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, but that might not represent the DOM element as you want it.

#### 3. `useRef`

You **could** add a `ref` to some element that is rendered by React. This gives you access to the corresponding `DOM-element` *(rendered by React)*, and you can inject your `DOM-element` *(returned by `querySelector()`)* using normal DOM methods.

This disables React to "track what's going on", and you might experience inconsistent state and hard-to-understand bugs.

e.g.:

```
export const StaticHtml = (props)=>{
    const ref = useRef();

    useEffect(() =>{
        var elm = document.getElementById('some-static-html');
        ref.current.appendChild(elm);
    }, []);

    return (<div ref={ ref }>
        some div
    </div>);
};
```

Comment: The third way of doing it (useRef) is so great, thanks!